# How do I change console font size and other properties on Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

As title says. I also want to be able to customize it so I can have different lines at different sizes at the same time, if that makes sense.

I tried the below code from someone on StackOverflow, but it didn't work.

```
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
cfi.cbSize = sizeof(cfi);
cfi.nFont = 0;
cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;                   // Width of each character in the font
cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 24;                  // Height
cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
std::wcscpy(cfi.FaceName, L"Consolas"); // Choose your font
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);

std::cout << "Font: Consolas, Size: 24\n";
```

Comment: You'll need to write your own custom console window to support that feature.  The console won't do that.

Comment: Is this for an app of your own that you plan to write / have already written?  If so, why not make it a GUI app?

Comment: To compile an application that uses `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx` function, define `_WIN32_WINNT` as `0x0500` or later. You try to use SetCurrentConsoleFontEx to change the console's font size. This affects the entire console window. If you want to have different lines at different sizes at the same time, as far as I'm concerned, this won't help you.